# Best practices for MATLAB message IDs?

Tags: matlab, exception, coding-style, warnings, error-code

When creation a MATLAB exception (MException object) or printing a warning or error message, MATLAB lets you supply a message ID that defines the except you're throwing.

The message ID is in the format:

```
component:mnemonic
```

For example, MATLAB's own undefined variable message ID is:

```
MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict
```

So when you use exceptions in your own code, what do you use for a message ID? Do you reuse MATLAB's default ones? Make up your own? What do you use for the component and mnemonic strings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I generally follow this pattern for error (or warning) [message identifiers](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html#bq9tdlq-1), where things in parentheses may or may not be present:

```
(className):(parentFunction):functionWhereErrorOccurs:descriptiveMnemonic
```

The components are:

- `className`: The name of the class, if the function where the error occurs is a method/constructor.
- `parentFunction`: If the function where the error occurs is a [subfunction in an m-file](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70666.html) or a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html), this would be the [primary m-file function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39629.html) or the parent of the nested function, respectively. You could therefore have multiple `parentFunction` components.
- `functionWhereErrorOccurs`: The name of this component is pretty self-explanatory. ;)
- `descriptiveMnemonic`: I stress *descriptive*. For example `inputError` doesn't really tell me anything, but `notEnoughInputs` makes it clear that I didn't pass enough arguments. I always use lower camel case for the mnemonic, where the first letter of a word is capitalized except for the very first word.

The `className` and `parentFunction` components *could* be considered somewhat redundant, since the [`stack` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html#bq9no0f-1) of the [`MException` class](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html#bq9l5ac) already identifies a complete path to the parent m-file and the line number of the error. However, one of the purposes of a [message identifier](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html#bq9tdlq-1) is that it allows you to *uniquely* identify an error for purposes other than just hunting down the source of the error.

Let's say you have a function `myFcn` and a class `myClass` that overloads `myFcn`. If you make an error message identifier for the first one be `myFcn:maxIterationsReached` and an error message identifier for the second one be `myClass:myFcn:maxIterationsReached`, this would allow you to, for example, set a breakpoint with [DBSTOP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dbstop.html) that halts execution only when this error is produced by `myClass\myFcn` and not `myFcn`. Likewise, unique *warning* message identifiers are useful in that you can specifically choose to [ignore warnings](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f3-39022.html) from *specific* functions while letting others be displayed.

Additionally, you could also include components in the identifier indicating that the function where the error occurs is located in a [package folder](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html) or a [private folder](http://www.mathworks.nl/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70335.html) (but this might make for a rather long identifier).

Comment: Hey... second time you've helped me.

Comment: @gnovice Do you use the fully qualified class name, with the package preceding?

Comment: @b3. It's up to you. I probably would just to make it as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3):

In my work I use YMA:(mainFunctionName):(descriptiveMnemonic), where YMA are simply my initials. For example, all the warnings and errors invoked in my [UIInspect utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methodspropertiescallbacks-of-an-object) have IDs similar to `YMA:uiinspect:XXX`.